# How does a semantic reasoner for protegé is made?

Tags: semantic-web, ontology

I'm new in "ontology world". I've been practicing Protegé and ontologies for 2 months and now I would like to understand (and if it is possible to create) a reasoner. But I don't know what is its structure, the language used by it and so on. 
Can you please me provide me a piece of information and something to read? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task of a reasoner is to produce inferences. Standard reasoning tasks are consistency check, realization, instance check and satisfiability. You can find all these defined in a number of books and articles about description logic.

Protege uses the OWL API to interface to reasoners so they are implementations of `OWLReasoner`. Not all of them are written in Java (e.g., FaCT++ is written in C++).
They are quite complex systems, so describing how to implement one takes chapters - too big for an answer here.
I'd recommend exploring the source code of a few of them. Open Source ones, off the top of my head: HermiT, FaCT++, Pellet, JFact, ELK.